# Toeplitz variance matrix with nlme

Tags: r, mixed-model, lme4-nlme, toeplitz

I would like to specify a Toeplitz variance matrix for the random effects of my `nlme` model in `R`. Is it possible ? More precisely, my model looks like

```
lme(y ~ dose, data = dat, random = list(Lot = pdSymm(~ 0+dose )))
```

but I want a Toeplitz matrix instead of the unstructured matrix which is here specified by `pdSymm`. There's no available pdToeplitz-like argument in `nlme`, but maybe there is another way to do this ?

I don't know if "Topelitz" is a standard terminology, this is the `SAS` terminology for a variance matrix with the only restriction that the diagonal entries are all equal.

(EDIT) Sorry, my above definition of Toeplitz is erroneous. A Toeplitz matrix $\Sigma=(m_{ij})$ is the case when $m_{ij}$ depends on $i$ and $j$ only through $|i-j|$. This is not what I'm looking for, I really want a variance matrix with the only restriction that the diagonal entries are all equal.

Comment: From `?pdClasses`: "Users may define their own `pdMat` classes by specifying a constructor function and, at a minimum, methods for the functions `pdConstruct`, `pdMatrix` and `coef`. For examples of these functions, see the methods for classes pdSymm and pdDiag." This question may be more appropriate for http://stackoverflow.com/.

Comment: What is the way to see the methods for pdSymm and pdDiag ? (typing methods(pdSymm) does not work). This question is very statistics-oriented, I'm not sure it is appropriate for stackoverflow.

Comment: `methods(pdConstruct)` will show you the methods for the function. You can use `getAnywhere` to look at the methods: `getAnywhere(pdConstruct.pdSymm)`

Comment: `methods(class=pdSymm)` might also be useful.

Comment: I've also read somewhere that using correlation=corARMA can be made equivalent to Toeplitz, haven't looked into detail into that though